# (hamburger icon) .reveal class on responsive menu with a toggleClass function is not positioning properly?

Tags: jquery, html, css

When I click the hamburger icon and the div containing the .reveal menu is revealed via the toggleclass function using css with transform: translate, and no matter where i position the .reveal with CSS it has a large gap between the beginning of the .responsive-menu element and responsive-menu.reveal class. This results in not aligning the menus text to just under the header and seems to start further down the .responsive-nav container class? any help would be greatly appreciated.

I would like the revealed menu to have the text start just under the header wrapper. Thanks

```js
  
        jQuery( document ).ready( function ($) {

          var $nav = $( '.responsive-nav' ),
              $ham = $( '#hamburger' );

          $ham.on( 'click', function () {

            $ham.toggleClass( 'open' );
            $nav.toggleClass( 'reveal' );

          } );

        } );
```

```css
/*------------------------------------*\
    MAIN
\*------------------------------------*/

/* global box-sizing */
*,
*:after,
*:before {
 -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
 box-sizing:border-box;
 -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
 font-smoothing:antialiased;
 text-rendering:optimizeLegibility;
}
/* html element 62.5% font-size for REM use */
html {
 font-size:62.5%;
}
body {
 font:300 11px/1.4 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 color:#444;
        
}
/* clear */
.clear:before,
.clear:after {
    content:' ';
    display:table;
}

.clear:after {
    clear:both;
}
.clear {
    *zoom:1;
}
img {
 max-width:100%;
 vertical-align:bottom;
}
a {
 color:#444;
 text-decoration:none;
}
a:hover {
 color:#444;
}
a:focus {
 outline:0;
}
a:hover,
a:active {
 outline:0;
}
input:focus {
 outline:0;
 border:1px solid #04A4CC;
}

/*------------------------------------*\
    STRUCTURE
\*------------------------------------*/

/* container all content ends in footer */

#container {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 71px;
    height: 100%;
    clear: both;
    z-index: 0;
        
}

@media (max-width: 450px){
    
    #container {
        display: flex;
        width: 100%;
        margin-top: 50px;
        height: 2000px;
        z-index: 0;
    }
}

/* header */

/* ==== WRAPPER FOR HEADER START ==== */

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    height: 80px;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #eee;
            
}

.wrapper.hidden {
    transform: translate3d(0,-100%,0);
}

/* ==== WRAPPER FOR HEADER @ MEDIA MAX WIDTH 450 PX ==== */



@media (max-width: 899px){
    
    .wrapper {
        display: flex;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 0;
        height: 70px;
        
    }
}

/* ==== WRAPPER FOR HEADER END ==== */

/* ===== SOCIAL MEDIA MENU START ==== */

/* ===== SOCIAL MENU MAX WIDTH 899 PX ==== */

@media only screen and (max-width: 899px){

    .socials {
        width: 20%;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        align-items: center;
        border-left: 2px solid #eee;
        margin-right: 2.5%;
        padding-left: 2.5%;
        
        
    }

    .socials ul li {
        height: 35px;
        width: 35px;
        
    }

    .socials ul {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        list-style: none;
        align-items: center;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
        justify-content: space-around;
                
    }

    .socials li img {
        max-height: 35px;
    }
}

/* ===== SOCIAL MENU MAX WIDTH 899 PX END ==== */

@media only screen and (min-width: 900px) {

    .socials {
        width: 17.5%;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        align-items: center;
        border-left: 2px solid #eee;
        margin-right: 2.5%;
        padding-left: 2.5%;
        
        
    }

    .socials ul li {
        height: 40px;
        width: 40px;
        
    }

    .socials ul {
        display: flex;
        list-style: none;
        align-items: center;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
        justify-content: space-around;
                
    }

    .socials li img {
        max-height: 40px;
    }
}

/* ===== SOCIAL MENU MIN WIDTH 900 PX END ==== */

/* ===== SOCIAL MEDIA MENU END ==== */

.header {

}
/* logo */

.logo-header {
        width: 27.5%;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        height: 80px;
        align-items: center;
        margin-left: 2.5%;
        
}

.logo-header img {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        height: 60px;
        width: 60px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 899px){
.logo-header {
        width: 27.5%;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        height: 70px;
        align-items: center;
        margin-left: 2.5%;
        
}

.logo-header img {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        height: 50px;
        width: 50px;
}
}

/* nav */

/* ===== FULLSCREEN NAVIGATION MENU START ==== */

/* ==== WORDPRESS PRIMARY MENU ABOVE 769 PX START ==== */

.site-nav {
    width: 50%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    font-size: 2.4rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    padding-right: 2.5%;
    
        
}

.site-nav ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    list-style: none;
    align-items: center;
    
    
}

.site-nav ul:before, .site-nav ul:after { content: ""; display: table; }
.site-nav ul:after { clear: both; }
.site-nav ul { *zoom: 1; }

.site-nav ul li  {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #949494;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-left: 1.6rem;
    
    
}
.site-nav ul li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #949494;
    text-decoration: none;
    
    
}
.site-nav ul li a:hover {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #555555;
    text-decoration: none;
    
}
li.current-menu-item a {
    color: #555555 !important;
    text-decoration: none;
    
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 899px){
    
    .site-nav {
        font-size: 2rem;
        padding-right: 3.5%;
    }
    
}

/* ==== WORDPRESS PRIMARY MENU ABOVE 769 PX END ==== */

/* ===== RESPOSIVE NAV START ==== */
/* ===== RESPOSIVE NAV START ==== */
/* ===== RESPOSIVE NAV START ==== */
/* ===== RESPOSIVE NAV START ==== */

/* ---- DONT SHOW RESPONSIVE IN FULL SCREEN ---- */


@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) {
.responsive-nav {
    display: none;
    }
    
.responsive-nav ul {
    display: none;
    }
    
.responsive-nav li {
    display: none;
    }

    }
/* ---- DONT SHOW RESPONSIVE IN FULL SCREEN END ---- */    
 
/* ===== RESPONSIVE NAV MOBILE MEDIA QUERY @ MIN-MAX 451-768 PX ==== */
    
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    
    .site-nav {
        display: none;
    }
    
 
    .responsive-nav {
        position: fixed;
        top: 70px;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        display: block;
        font-size: 2.4rem;
        font-weight: 400;
        width: 50vw;
        height: 100vh;
        font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
        transform: translateX( 100% );
        transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
        
    }
    
    .responsive-nav.reveal {
        transform: translateX( 0 );
          
    }
    
    .responsive-nav ul {
        display: block;
        padding-left: 0px !important;
        font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
        font-size: 2rem;
        list-style: none;
                
   
    }
    
    .responsive-nav li {
        display: block;
        padding: 0;
        position: relative;    
    }
    
    .responsive-nav a:hover {
        color: #555555;
    }
    
    .responsive-nav li:first-child {
        display: block;
        padding-top: 10px;
        position: relative;
        
    }
    
    .responsive-nav a {
        display: block;
        padding: 0;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #949494;
        position: relative;   
    }
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    
    .responsive-hide {
        width: 47.5%;
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: row;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        padding-right: 2.5%;
    }
    
    .toggle-nav {
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: row;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        align-items: center;
        height: 70px;
        
        
    }
    
    #hamburger {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        width: 36px;
        height: 20px;
        color: #949494;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
        -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
        transition: .5s ease-in-out;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    #hamburger span {
        color: #949494;
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        height: 2px;
        width: 100%;
        background: #949494;
        border-radius: 2px;
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
        -webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
        transition: .25s ease-in-out;
    }
    
    #hamburger span:nth-child(1) {
        top: 0px;
    }

    #hamburger span:nth-child(2) {
        top: 8px;
    }

    #hamburger span:nth-child(3) {
        top: 16px;
    }
    
    #hamburger.open span:nth-child(1) {
        top: 8px;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(135deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(135deg);
        transform: rotate(135deg);
    }

    #hamburger.open span:nth-child(2) {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transition: 0.25s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: 0.25s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: 0.25s ease-in-out;
        transition: 0.25s ease-in-out;    
    }

    #hamburger.open span:nth-child(3) {
        top: 8px;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(-135deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(-135deg);
        transform: rotate(-135deg);
    }
    
    #hamburger:hover {
        cursor: pointer;
        color: #555555;
    }
}

/* ===== HAMBURGER MOBILE MEDIA QUERY @ MEDIA QUERY @ MIN-MAX 451-768 PX END ==== */
```

```html
<!-- header -->
   <header class="wrapper">
                            
                            <div class="logo-header">
                                <img src= "http://testsiteclash.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/luke-logo-layers-copy.png">
                            </div>
                            
                            <!-- responsive nav -->
                            <div class="responsive-hide">
                                <div class="toggle-nav">
                                    <div id="hamburger">
                                        <span></span>
                                        <span></span>
                                        <span></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <nav class="responsive-nav">
                                    <ul id="reveal" class="responsive-nav"><li id="menu-item-32" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-5 current_page_item menu-item-32"><a href="http://testsiteclash.co.uk/">Home</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-31" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-31"><a href="http://testsiteclash.co.uk/about">About</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-30" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-30"><a href="http://testsiteclash.co.uk/gallery">Gallery</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-29" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-29"><a href="http://testsiteclash.co.uk/contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>                                </nav>
                            </div>
                            <!-- responsive nav -->
                            
                            <!-- nav -->
                            <nav class="site-nav">
                                <ul><li id="menu-item-9" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-9"><a href="http://testsiteclash.co.uk/">Home</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-10" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-10"><a href="http://testsiteclash.co.uk/about">About</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-47" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-47"><a href="http://testsiteclash.co.uk/blog">Blog</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-18" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-18"><a href="http://testsiteclash.co.uk/contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>                            </nav>
                            <!-- /nav -->
                            
                                                       
                            <div class="socials">
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://testsiteclash.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/facebook-icon.png" id="facebook" onmouseover="newPicture()" onmouseout="oldPicture()"/></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://testsiteclash.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/insta-icon.png" id="instagram" onmouseover="newPicture1()" onmouseout="oldPicture1()"/></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://testsiteclash.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/twitter-icon.png" id="twitter" onmouseover="newPicture2()" onmouseout="oldPicture2()"/></a></li>
                                    <!--<li><a href="#"><img src="http://testsiteclash.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/pinterest-icon.png" id="pinterest" onmouseover="newPicture3()" onmouseout="oldPicture3()"/></a></li>-->
                                </ul>
                            </div>

     

   </header>
   <!-- /header -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like all you need to do is remove the `.responsive-nav` class from `#reveal`. No need for both to have that class. The reason that messes up the layout is the class `.responsive-nav` has `top: 70px`, that is being applied to the outer `nav` and the inner `ul#reveal` creating unnecessary space between the top of the `nav.responsive-nav` and top of `ul#reveal.responsive-nav`

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  var $nav = $('.responsive-nav'),
    $ham = $('#hamburger');

  $ham.on('click', function() {

    $ham.toggleClass('open');
    $nav.toggleClass('reveal');

  });

});
```

```css
/*------------------------------------*\
    MAIN
\*------------------------------------*/


/* global box-sizing */

*,
*:after,
*:before {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-smoothing: antialiased;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}


/* html element 62.5% font-size for REM use */

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
  font: 300 11px/1.4 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #444;
}


/* clear */

.clear:before,
.clear:after {
  content: ' ';
  display: table;
}

.clear:after {
  clear: both;
}

.clear {
  *zoom: 1;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

a {
  color: #444;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: #444;
}

a:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

a:hover,
a:active {
  outline: 0;
}

input:focus {
  outline: 0;
  border: 1px solid #04A4CC;
}


/*------------------------------------*\
    STRUCTURE
\*------------------------------------*/


/* container all content ends in footer */

#container {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 71px;
  height: 100%;
  clear: both;
  z-index: 0;
}

@media (max-width: 450px) {
  #container {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 50px;
    height: 2000px;
    z-index: 0;
  }
}


/* header */


/* ==== WRAPPER FOR HEADER START ==== */

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  height: 80px;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #eee;
}

.wrapper.hidden {
  transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
}


/* ==== WRAPPER FOR HEADER @ MEDIA MAX WIDTH 450 PX ==== */

@media (max-width: 899px) {
  .wrapper {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    height: 70px;
  }
}


/* ==== WRAPPER FOR HEADER END ==== */


/* ===== SOCIAL MEDIA MENU START ==== */


/* ===== SOCIAL MENU MAX WIDTH 899 PX ==== */

@media only screen and (max-width: 899px) {
  .socials {
    width: 20%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
    border-left: 2px solid #eee;
    margin-right: 2.5%;
    padding-left: 2.5%;
  }
  .socials ul li {
    height: 35px;
    width: 35px;
  }
  .socials ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    list-style: none;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: space-around;
  }
  .socials li img {
    max-height: 35px;
  }
}


/* ===== SOCIAL MENU MAX WIDTH 899 PX END ==== */

@media only screen and (min-width: 900px) {
  .socials {
    width: 17.5%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
    border-left: 2px solid #eee;
    margin-right: 2.5%;
    padding-left: 2.5%;
  }
  .socials ul li {
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
  }
  .socials ul {
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: space-around;
  }
  .socials li img {
    max-height: 40px;
  }
}


/* ===== SOCIAL MENU MIN WIDTH 900 PX END ==== */


/* ===== SOCIAL MEDIA MENU END ==== */

.header {}


/* logo */

.logo-header {
  width: 27.5%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 80px;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: 2.5%;
}

.logo-header img {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 899px) {
  .logo-header {
    width: 27.5%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    height: 70px;
    align-items: center;
    margin-left: 2.5%;
  }
  .logo-header img {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
  }
}


/* nav */


/* ===== FULLSCREEN NAVIGATION MENU START ==== */


/* ==== WORDPRESS PRIMARY MENU ABOVE 769 PX START ==== */

.site-nav {
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  font-size: 2.4rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  padding-right: 2.5%;
}

.site-nav ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style: none;
  align-items: center;
}

.site-nav ul:before,
.site-nav ul:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.site-nav ul:after {
  clear: both;
}

.site-nav ul {
  *zoom: 1;
}

.site-nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #949494;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-left: 1.6rem;
}

.site-nav ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #949494;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.site-nav ul li a:hover {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #555555;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li.current-menu-item a {
  color: #555555 !important;
  text-decoration: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 899px) {
  .site-nav {
    font-size: 2rem;
    padding-right: 3.5%;
  }
}


/* ==== WORDPRESS PRIMARY MENU ABOVE 769 PX END ==== */


/* ===== RESPOSIVE NAV START ==== */


/* ===== RESPOSIVE NAV START ==== */


/* ===== RESPOSIVE NAV START ==== */


/* ===== RESPOSIVE NAV START ==== */


/* ---- DONT SHOW RESPONSIVE IN FULL SCREEN ---- */

@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) {
  .responsive-nav {
    display: none;
  }
  .responsive-nav ul {
    display: none;
  }
  .responsive-nav li {
    display: none;
  }
}


/* ---- DONT SHOW RESPONSIVE IN FULL SCREEN END ---- */


/* ===== RESPONSIVE NAV MOBILE MEDIA QUERY @ MIN-MAX 451-768 PX ==== */

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .site-nav {
    display: none;
  }
  .responsive-nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 70px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    display: block;
    font-size: 2.4rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    width: 50vw;
    height: 100vh;
    font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    transform: translateX( 100%);
    transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
  }
  .responsive-nav.reveal {
    transform: translateX( 0);
  }
  .responsive-nav ul {
    display: block;
    padding-left: 0px !important;
    font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 2rem;
    list-style: none;
  }
  .responsive-nav li {
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
  }
  .responsive-nav a:hover {
    color: #555555;
  }
  .responsive-nav li:first-child {
    display: block;
    padding-top: 10px;
    position: relative;
  }
  .responsive-nav a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #949494;
    position: relative;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .responsive-hide {
    width: 47.5%;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    padding-right: 2.5%;
  }
  .toggle-nav {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
    height: 70px;
  }
  #hamburger {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    width: 36px;
    height: 20px;
    color: #949494;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  #hamburger span {
    color: #949494;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    height: 2px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #949494;
    border-radius: 2px;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
    transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  }
  #hamburger span:nth-child(1) {
    top: 0px;
  }
  #hamburger span:nth-child(2) {
    top: 8px;
  }
  #hamburger span:nth-child(3) {
    top: 16px;
  }
  #hamburger.open span:nth-child(1) {
    top: 8px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(135deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(135deg);
    transform: rotate(135deg);
  }
  #hamburger.open span:nth-child(2) {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: 0.25s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: 0.25s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: 0.25s ease-in-out;
    transition: 0.25s ease-in-out;
  }
  #hamburger.open span:nth-child(3) {
    top: 8px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-135deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-135deg);
    transform: rotate(-135deg);
  }
  #hamburger:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #555555;
  }
}


/* ===== HAMBURGER MOBILE MEDIA QUERY @ MEDIA QUERY @ MIN-MAX 451-768 PX END ==== */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- header -->
<header class="wrapper">

  <div class="logo-header">
    <img src="http://testsiteclash.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/luke-logo-layers-copy.png">
  </div>

  <!-- responsive nav -->
  <div class="responsive-hide">
    <div class="toggle-nav">
      <div id="hamburger">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <nav class="responsive-nav">
      <ul id="reveal">
        <li id="menu-item-32" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-5 current_page_item menu-item-32"><a href="http://testsiteclash.co.uk/">Home</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-31" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-31"><a href="http://testsiteclash.co.uk/about">About</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-30" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-30"><a href="http://testsiteclash.co.uk/gallery">Gallery</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-29" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-29"><a href="http://testsiteclash.co.uk/contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <!-- responsive nav -->

  <!-- nav -->
  <nav class="site-nav">
    <ul>
      <li id="menu-item-9" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-9"><a href="http://testsiteclash.co.uk/">Home</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-10" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-10"><a href="http://testsiteclash.co.uk/about">About</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-47" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-47"><a href="http://testsiteclash.co.uk/blog">Blog</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-18" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-18"><a href="http://testsiteclash.co.uk/contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <!-- /nav -->


  <div class="socials">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://testsiteclash.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/facebook-icon.png" id="facebook" onmouseover="newPicture()" onmouseout="oldPicture()" /></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://testsiteclash.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/insta-icon.png" id="instagram" onmouseover="newPicture1()" onmouseout="oldPicture1()" /></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://testsiteclash.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/twitter-icon.png" id="twitter" onmouseover="newPicture2()" onmouseout="oldPicture2()" /></a>
      </li>
      <!--<li><a href="#"><img src="http://testsiteclash.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/pinterest-icon.png" id="pinterest" onmouseover="newPicture3()" onmouseout="oldPicture3()"/></a></li>-->
    </ul>
  </div>


</header>
<!-- /header -->
```

Comment: not entirely sure what you mean as there is no #reveal? only .responsive-nav.reveal {
    transform: translateX( 0);
  }

Comment: do you mean by the ul id is assigned as an array? <nav class="responsive-nav">
                                    <?php
                                        wp_nav_menu( array(
                                            'theme_location' => 'responsive-menu',
                                            'menu_class'     => 'responsive-nav',
                                            'menu_id'     => 'reveal',
                                            
                                            ) );
                                    ?>
                                </nav>

Comment: @PaulStephenDavis `<ul id="reveal" class="responsive-nav">`

Answer (score 0):

```js
jQuery( document ).ready( function ($) {

          var $nav = $( '.responsive-nav' ),
              $ham = $( '#hamburger' );

          $ham.on( 'click', function () {

            $ham.toggleClass( 'open' );
            $nav.toggleClass( 'reveal' );

          } );

        } );
```

```css
/*------------------------------------*\
    MAIN
\*------------------------------------*/

/* global box-sizing */
*,
*:after,
*:before {
 -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
 box-sizing:border-box;
 -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
 font-smoothing:antialiased;
 text-rendering:optimizeLegibility;
}
/* html element 62.5% font-size for REM use */
html {
 font-size:62.5%;
}
body {
 font:300 11px/1.4 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 color:#444;
        
}
/* clear */
.clear:before,
.clear:after {
    content:' ';
    display:table;
}

.clear:after {
    clear:both;
}
.clear {
    *zoom:1;
}
img {
 max-width:100%;
 vertical-align:bottom;
}
a {
 color:#444;
 text-decoration:none;
}
a:hover {
 color:#444;
}
a:focus {
 outline:0;
}
a:hover,
a:active {
 outline:0;
}
input:focus {
 outline:0;
 border:1px solid #04A4CC;
}

/*------------------------------------*\
    STRUCTURE
\*------------------------------------*/

/* container all content ends in footer */

#container {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 71px;
    height: 100%;
    clear: both;
    z-index: 0;
        
}

@media (max-width: 450px){
    
    #container {
        display: flex;
        width: 100%;
        margin-top: 50px;
        height: 2000px;
        z-index: 0;
    }
}

/* header */

/* ==== WRAPPER FOR HEADER START ==== */

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    height: 80px;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #eee;
            
}

.wrapper.hidden {
    transform: translate3d(0,-100%,0);
}

/* ==== WRAPPER FOR HEADER @ MEDIA MAX WIDTH 450 PX ==== */



@media (max-width: 899px){
    
    .wrapper {
        display: flex;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 0;
        height: 70px;
        
    }
}

/* ==== WRAPPER FOR HEADER END ==== */

/* ===== SOCIAL MEDIA MENU START ==== */

/* ===== SOCIAL MENU MAX WIDTH 899 PX ==== */

@media only screen and (max-width: 899px){

    .socials {
        width: 20%;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        align-items: center;
        border-left: 2px solid #eee;
        margin-right: 2.5%;
        padding-left: 2.5%;
        
        
    }

    .socials ul li {
        height: 35px;
        width: 35px;
        
    }

    .socials ul {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        list-style: none;
        align-items: center;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
        justify-content: space-around;
                
    }

    .socials li img {
        max-height: 35px;
    }
}

/* ===== SOCIAL MENU MAX WIDTH 899 PX END ==== */

@media only screen and (min-width: 900px) {

    .socials {
        width: 17.5%;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        align-items: center;
        border-left: 2px solid #eee;
        margin-right: 2.5%;
        padding-left: 2.5%;
        
        
    }

    .socials ul li {
        height: 40px;
        width: 40px;
        
    }

    .socials ul {
        display: flex;
        list-style: none;
        align-items: center;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
        justify-content: space-around;
                
    }

    .socials li img {
        max-height: 40px;
    }
}

/* ===== SOCIAL MENU MIN WIDTH 900 PX END ==== */

/* ===== SOCIAL MEDIA MENU END ==== */

.header {

}
/* logo */

.logo-header {
        width: 27.5%;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        height: 80px;
        align-items: center;
        margin-left: 2.5%;
        
}

.logo-header img {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        height: 60px;
        width: 60px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 899px){
.logo-header {
        width: 27.5%;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        height: 70px;
        align-items: center;
        margin-left: 2.5%;
        
}

.logo-header img {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        height: 50px;
        width: 50px;
}
}

/* nav */

/* ===== FULLSCREEN NAVIGATION MENU START ==== */

/* ==== WORDPRESS PRIMARY MENU ABOVE 769 PX START ==== */

.site-nav {
    width: 50%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    font-size: 2.4rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    padding-right: 2.5%;
    
        
}

.site-nav ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    list-style: none;
    align-items: center;
    
    
}

.site-nav ul:before, .site-nav ul:after { content: ""; display: table; }
.site-nav ul:after { clear: both; }
.site-nav ul { *zoom: 1; }

.site-nav ul li  {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #949494;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-left: 1.6rem;
    
    
}
.site-nav ul li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #949494;
    text-decoration: none;
    
    
}
.site-nav ul li a:hover {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #555555;
    text-decoration: none;
    
}
li.current-menu-item a {
    color: #555555 !important;
    text-decoration: none;
    
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 899px){
    
    .site-nav {
        font-size: 2rem;
        padding-right: 3.5%;
    }
    
}

/* ==== WORDPRESS PRIMARY MENU ABOVE 769 PX END ==== */

/* ===== RESPOSIVE NAV START ==== */
/* ===== RESPOSIVE NAV START ==== */
/* ===== RESPOSIVE NAV START ==== */
/* ===== RESPOSIVE NAV START ==== */

/* ---- DONT SHOW RESPONSIVE IN FULL SCREEN ---- */


@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) {
.responsive-nav {
    display: none;
    }
    
.responsive-nav ul {
    display: none;
    }
    
.responsive-nav li {
    display: none;
    }

    }
/* ---- DONT SHOW RESPONSIVE IN FULL SCREEN END ---- */    
 
/* ===== RESPONSIVE NAV MOBILE MEDIA QUERY @ MIN-MAX 451-768 PX ==== */
    
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    
    .site-nav {
        display: none;
    }
    
 
    .responsive-nav {
        position: fixed;
        top: 70px;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        display: block;
        font-size: 2.4rem;
        font-weight: 400;
        width: 50vw;
        height: 100vh;
        font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
        transform: translateX( 100% );
        transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
        
    }
    
    .responsive-nav.reveal {
        transform: translateX( 0 );
          
    }
    
    .responsive-nav ul {
        display: block;
        padding-left: 0px !important;
        font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
        font-size: 2rem;
        list-style: none;
                
   
    }
    
    .responsive-nav li {
        display: block;
        padding: 0;
        position: relative;    
    }
    
    .responsive-nav a:hover {
        color: #555555;
    }
    
    .responsive-nav li:first-child {
        display: block;
        padding-top: 10px;
        position: relative;
        
    }
    
    .responsive-nav a {
        display: block;
        padding: 0;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #949494;
        position: relative;   
    }
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    
    .responsive-hide {
        width: 47.5%;
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: row;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        padding-right: 2.5%;
    }
    
    .toggle-nav {
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: row;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        align-items: center;
        height: 70px;
        
        
    }
    
    #hamburger {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        width: 36px;
        height: 20px;
        color: #949494;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
        -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
        transition: .5s ease-in-out;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    #hamburger span {
        color: #949494;
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        height: 2px;
        width: 100%;
        background: #949494;
        border-radius: 2px;
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
        -webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
        transition: .25s ease-in-out;
    }
    
    #hamburger span:nth-child(1) {
        top: 0px;
    }

    #hamburger span:nth-child(2) {
        top: 8px;
    }

    #hamburger span:nth-child(3) {
        top: 16px;
    }
    
    #hamburger.open span:nth-child(1) {
        top: 8px;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(135deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(135deg);
        transform: rotate(135deg);
    }

    #hamburger.open span:nth-child(2) {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transition: 0.25s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: 0.25s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: 0.25s ease-in-out;
        transition: 0.25s ease-in-out;    
    }

    #hamburger.open span:nth-child(3) {
        top: 8px;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(-135deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(-135deg);
        transform: rotate(-135deg);
    }
    
    #hamburger:hover {
        cursor: pointer;
        color: #555555;
    }
}

/* ===== HAMBURGER MOBILE MEDIA QUERY @ MEDIA QUERY @ MIN-MAX 451-768 PX END ==== */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- header -->
   <header class="wrapper">
                            
                            <div class="logo-header">
                                <img src= "http://testsiteclash.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/luke-logo-layers-copy.png">
                            </div>
                            
                            <!-- responsive nav -->
                            <div class="responsive-hide">
                                <div class="toggle-nav">
                                    <div id="hamburger">
                                        <span></span>
                                        <span></span>
                                        <span></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <nav class="responsive-nav">
                                    <ul id="reveal" class=""><li id="menu-item-32" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-5 current_page_item menu-item-32"><a href="http://testsiteclash.co.uk/">Home</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-31" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-31"><a href="http://testsiteclash.co.uk/about">About</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-30" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-30"><a href="http://testsiteclash.co.uk/gallery">Gallery</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-29" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-29"><a href="http://testsiteclash.co.uk/contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>                                </nav>
                            </div>
                            <!-- responsive nav -->
                            
                            <!-- nav -->
                            <nav class="site-nav">
                                <ul><li id="menu-item-9" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-9"><a href="http://testsiteclash.co.uk/">Home</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-10" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-10"><a href="http://testsiteclash.co.uk/about">About</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-47" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-47"><a href="http://testsiteclash.co.uk/blog">Blog</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-18" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-18"><a href="http://testsiteclash.co.uk/contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>                            </nav>
                            <!-- /nav -->
                            
                                                       
                            <div class="socials">
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://testsiteclash.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/facebook-icon.png" id="facebook" onmouseover="newPicture()" onmouseout="oldPicture()"/></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://testsiteclash.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/insta-icon.png" id="instagram" onmouseover="newPicture1()" onmouseout="oldPicture1()"/></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://testsiteclash.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/twitter-icon.png" id="twitter" onmouseover="newPicture2()" onmouseout="oldPicture2()"/></a></li>
                                    <!--<li><a href="#"><img src="http://testsiteclash.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/pinterest-icon.png" id="pinterest" onmouseover="newPicture3()" onmouseout="oldPicture3()"/></a></li>-->
                                </ul>
                            </div>

     

   </header>
   <!-- /header -->
```